# returning true when the codition is false in c# rest

Tags: c#, sql

am trying to make a simple api for login in `c#` but my checking condition returns `true` even if the data is not present in database. here is my model`login.cs`

```
public string username { get; set; }
public string password { get; set; }

public string AddEmployees(Login Emp)
{
    try
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        SqlCommand com;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DOTNET;Initial Catalog=edin;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

        com = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from data where name='" + username + "' and phone='" + password + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            return "success";//returns this always
        }
        else
        {
            return "error";
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception aa)
    {
        return aa.ToString();
    }

}
```

and my `Controller`

```
public string AddEmployees(Login Emp)
{
    Login employe = new Login();
    var response = employe.AddEmployees(Emp);
    return response;
}
```

where am wrong..? or am i missing some code ..can anyone help

Comment: Try putting it into a list and then counting it, maybe the count is returning 0 even if nothing is found?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` is always going to return a value (either 0 or 1), so `if (reader.Read())` will always be `true`

Comment: ExecuteScalar is better to be used in this case !

Comment: oh sorry on mistake in question.actually even the `username`and`password` does not exists on table also its returning `sucess`

Comment: You have many incorrect statements. Select `*` from data where name='" + `Emp.username` + "' and `password`='" + `Emp.password` + "'". As count(*) will at least give you 0 or count so reader will always be read

Comment: And strongly suggest you read up on sql injection. And never store passwords as plain text - you store a hash of it

Comment: @StephenMuecke sir am aware of it but its just a learnig so thats why am using like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont use count. select a field instead. HasRows() will help what you are looking for. try this:

```
SqlDataReader reader = null;
    SqlCommand com;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DOTNET;Initial Catalog=edin;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

    com = new SqlCommand("Select name from data where name='" + username + "' and phone='" + password + "'", con);
    con.Open();
    reader = com.ExecuteReader();


    return reader.HasRows() ? "success" : "error";
    con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were trying to select the actual rows themselves, that code would probably behave as you expect, returning `true` if rows were found or `false` otherwise.

You're doing a `Select count(*)` though, which is going to return `0` if no matching records were found, so there's always *something* returned.

Try using [`ExecuteScalar()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `ExecuteReader`. It'll return your single value (the row count), which you can use to determine success or failure.

```
int rowCount = com.ExecuteScalar();
return (rowCount == 0) ? "failure" : "success";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
Select count(*) from data where name= ...
```

so you will always have result , even if specified user doesn't exists in db. So you will always get reader.Read() true.

On the other hand i don't thing that returning string as operation result is good choice. And remember to avoid concatenation in sql query. Rather that use sql parameters , because this kind of creating query:

```
Select count(*) from data where name='" + username + "' and phone='" + password + "'"
```

is very risky, because of sql injection.